# error in aaply function when applied to data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table, plyr

I have data as follows:

```
SUBJECT_Blinded LINE    MODULE  CENTRE_Blinded  STUDYPER    PACKID  SACDPDAT    SACDP1   SACRTDAT   SACRT1
1   1201001 8   SPX 1201    8   14096   2010-04-25  42  2011-06-22  0
2   1201001 4   SPX 1201    5   10615   2010-01-03  42  2011-01-31  9
```

Output of dput(sac[1:2,]):

```
structure(list(SUBJECT_Blinded = c(1201001, 1201001), LINE = c(8, 
5), MODULE = c("SPX", "SPX"), CENTRE_Blinded = c(1201, 1201), 
STUDYPER = c(7, 4), PACKID = c(10096, 10595), SACDPDAT = structure(c(1335304800, 
1325545200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
SACDP1 = c(35, 35), SACRTDAT = structure(c(1340316000, 1327964400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SACRT1 = c(0, 
9)), .Names = c("SUBJECT_Blinded", "LINE", "MODULE", "CENTRE_Blinded", 
"STUDYPER", "PACKID", "SACDPDAT", "SACDP1", "SACRTDAT", "SACRT1"
), sorted = c("SUBJECT_Blinded", "PACKID"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000300788>)
```

When I'm trying to execute command:

```
sac[,treatment_days := aaply(sac, 1, function(x){list(format(seq(from = x[7], to = x[10], by = "1 day"),"%Y-%m-%d"))})]
```

error appears:
    Error: 'from' must be of length 1
Why does it work like that?

Comment: The error is coming from `seq`. The tenth column is not going to have datetime values in the first place. Furthermore, why would you be using an `aaply` function. That is for arrays and you clearly do not have an arrays as your first argument. Arrays and matrices need to be all the same mode and will not be capable of holding POSIXct objects.

Comment: Maybe you should back up and say what you are really trying to do. You are proposing to put results of varying length into very reular data structures. Why should this succeed at all?

Comment: Results of varying length? No, I'm trying to put there lists, one list for each row. List is ONE element. The list of course may vary in length, but it should work, I can put list in data.table...

Comment: I'm trying to generate lists of characters which would be used later to represent days. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for something like this:

```
 ## Note the use of list(list( . ))
 sac[  , treatment_days := list(list(seq(from=SACDPDAT, to= SACRTDAT)))
       , by=list(SACDPDAT, SACRTDAT)
     ]
```

A few points:

1. use `list( list( ))`  to return a column that is itself a list.  (The outter `list()` is for data.table's syntax)
2. Are you sure you want a column that is a list?  Does it fit your ultimate goal?  A taller table might be a lot better.  Especially given data.table's quick access to specific rows, using keys
3. The above still needs to be formatted, and the `by` in `seq` needs to be adjusted to your needs.